# Colours in bargraph in faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to plot a bar graph with percentage on y axis and a categorical variable with 6 categories on X axis. Faceting is done by another categorical variable which has 7 levels.
I want to add different colors to bars representing 6 levels of variable x in each facet.

I tried writing this code:

```
ggplot(data= choices, aes(x=pre2_Altdrinks)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), alpha=0.75) + 
    facet_grid(~Residence) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
labs(title = "Alternate drinks protective behaviour across different residence status",
         x = "alternate drinks", y= "Percentage")
```

It generates this graph with no colors:
[image: graph]

Then i tried this code:

```
ggplot(data= choices, aes(x=pre2_Altdrinks,fill= pre2_Altdrinks )) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), alpha=0.75)+ 
    facet_grid(~Residence) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
labs(title = "Alternate drinks protective behaviour across different residence status",
         x = "alternate drinks", y= "Percentage")
```

It gives me:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Answer (score 1):

try placing `fill = Residence` in the `geom_bar` aesthetics call.

Comment: you probably meant `pre2_Altdrinks`?

Comment: I mean `geom_bar(aes(fill = residence, y = etc...`. It might work in the ggplot call too, but it's hard to test with no data.